# Configuring GRASS 7 to work alongside QGIS 2.18?

Tags: grass-gis, installation, windows, qgis-2.18

All day I was struggling with QGIS 18 and GRASS 7.
My mission was simple: import a file in QGIS 2.18, run **v.clean** and then go home. Unfortunately it turned out that my mission was not that easy.

First of all, although I read everywhere that GRASS is now a component of QGIS 2.18, when I tried running the plugins, received an error telling me that I needed to configure the working directory for GRASS.

I tried different things (see the list below) doing that and I failed many times.

- Installing GRASS 7 separately and moving the contents of the folder in the apps subfolder of QGIS, in order to be able to point it in the program
- Found out that there already was a grass installation in my QGIS folder. Linked the application to that folder
- Read what was written in the QGIS documentation about configuring grass, followed the steps, failed.
- Installed MSYS, linked the folder to the corresponding one in QGIS (heard that GRASS 7 did not require MSYS)
- Started the GUI of the software, got an error while trying to import the shapefile, a module (forgot the name) was missing and the command failed.

Can anyone guide me step-by-step on how I can configure the software in order to work properly?

Thinking as a last resort downgrading to QGIS 2.14 and hoping for the best.

Comment: Rather than asking someone write out the steps for you I think you should list the precise steps of your latest attempt to let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: If you are running the latest QGIS 2.18.10 on Windows, the only solution for now is downgrade to 2.18.9: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16777 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246022/unable-to-run-any-grass-7-algorithms-in-qgis-2-18-10-on-windows-764

Comment: Why is my question duplicate? My QGIS runs on Windows 10.
Thank you!